# htaccess is redirecting seems to be ignoring not rewritecond

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the following scenario and I've spent hours trying to work out why it's redirecting.

Here's my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mypage/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^mypage/?$ /testing.php [NC,L]
```

When I browse to http://www.example.com/mypage it is redirecting to https://www.example.com/mypage

I would expected because of the !^/mypage/?$ condition it wouldn't, however, I seem to be completely wrong!

Can someone please put me out of my misery and let me know why this isn't working?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *pulls trigger of a gun* <-- oh, that is not what you meant... sorry :( On a more serious note: You are testing with a 301 redirect. Never, ever do that. I am pretty sure that you are seeing the effect of an old, wrong, cached redirect. Clear your cache and it should magically fix itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because 2nd rule is rewriting `/mypage` to `/testing.php` and your `REQUEST_URI` becomes  `/testing.php` in the 2nd loop of `mod_rewrite`.

Have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(mypage/?|testing\.php)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteRule ^mypage/?$ /testing.php [NC,L]
```

Also make sure to test it in a new browser to avoid 301 caching issues.